# mysql triggers to multiple table and insert new id to table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have 4 table:

```
table a (id (auto_increment), id_b , id_c, id_d(foreign_key from table b,c,d) , column)
table b (id auto_increment, column)
table c (id auto_increment, column)
table d (id auto_increment, column)
```

when there's event table a, b, c, d inserted, must copy to table a, b, c, d in other database. (note: in other database table a,b,c,d already has data, so auto_increment isn't identical to current database)

I want to create triggers for that, but I'm confused how can I fill id_b, id_c, id_d from table b, c, d in other database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_b
AFTER INSERT
ON db1.table_b
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT IGNORE INTO db2.table_b (column)
VALUES (NEW.column);
```

The same for `table_c` and `table_d`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_a
AFTER INSERT
ON db1.table_a
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO db2.table_a (id_b, id_c, id_d, column)
SELECT b.id, c.id, d.id, vals.column_a
FROM ( SELECT b.column column_b, c.column column_c, d.column column_d, NEW.column column_a
       FROM db1.table_b b
       JOIN db1.table_c c
       JOIN db1.table_d d
       WHERE b.id = NEW.id_b
         AND c.id = NEW.id_c
         AND d.id = NEW.id_d ) vals
JOIN db2.table_b b ON b.column = vals.column_b
JOIN db2.table_c c ON c.column = vals.column_c
JOIN db2.table_d d ON c.column = vals.column_d;
```

PS. Not tested, minor errors possible, check and debug.

PPS. The structure assumes that `column` in tables `b`, `c` and `d` is defined as unique.

Comment: thank you. butthe `column` is not defined unique. so there is no way to achieve this if `column` not unique?

Comment: *column is not defined unique* If so the `table_a` will be joined to a random record in `table_b` with the same `column` value. And you can do nothing. No way to determine what record with the same `column` was joined to a particular record from `table_a` - source `id` was altered to unknown value during transfer.

Comment: No `ON` clause for the subquery's `JOINs`?

Comment: @RickJames Why not? [JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) - *join_specification* (ON clause) is optional. This is equal to `ON true`. It is a JOIN variant of cartesian.

Comment: @Akina - Do we know that those tables have only one row?  Or that a Cross Join is desired?

Comment: @RickJames *Do we know that those tables have only one row?* We have not seen source DDLs, so I don't know. But OP says that *the `column` is not defined unique* - this means that the database is not normalized and interferences are possible. *Or that a Cross Join is desired?* `JOIN` == `INNER JOIN ON true` == `CROSS JOIN ON true` (INNER and CROSS are synonims in MySQL).